# Java, JXMapKit: How to catch java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, exception, openstreetmap, swingx, jxmapkit

I've implemented JXMapKit in my Java application. How can the `java.net.UnknownHostException ("SEVERE: Failed to load a tile at url: ...")`, which is raised f.ex. when the internet connection is down, be caught? Do I need to override something from the library?

I have tried to surround all of the lines that have anything to do with the map with `try {} catch (Exception e) {}` but it seems that the exception cannot be caught that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JXMapKit, but if you cannot catch an exception it must be because it it thrown on another thread. In such cases you can use [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to get the exceptions.